# Which Gentoo ebuild provide phpize binary?

Tags: php, gentoo

could someone point to the ebuild which provides phpize binary? It's mainly used to compile packages with php pecl.

I'm on a Gentoo up-to-date machine, so I'm also on PHP5.5.

Comment: Due to an unknown reason `/usr/bin/phpize` was a broken symlink to real phpize binary path provided by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

There is a generic way to find out which package provides a certain binary.

```
emerge app-portage/pfl
```

Installs a program called e-file, which allows you to

> host ~ # e-file phpize
>   *  dev-lang/php

Answer (score 0):

/usr/bin/phpize is created by the eselect php module.
Try *eselect php* to get help.